# Find if the value is same in different items in cosmos db document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to cosmos db and trying to write a query to check if the value of one attribute in the item is same/repeated in other items in the document.

Sample JSON structure

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "resetPassword": [
        {
            "oneTimeCode": "hug3jh",
            "type": "code"
        }
    ],
    "expirationDateTime": 1651234557057,
    
}
```

Query

```
Select * from password-reset.resetPassword 
where oneTimeCode  // When I do this I get an error that cannot resolve oneTimeCode

If I was doing this in SQL, I would write

Select id, count(resetPassword.oneTimeCode) 
from password-reset 
group by resetPassword.oneTimeCode 
having count(resetPassword.oneTimeCode) > 1
```

How do I do this in Cosmos db? I am using SQL API

Comment: `where oneTimeCode` would result in a syntax error. You need to name the collection alias (e.g. `where password-reset.oneTimeCode`) - but also, what is the rest of the WHERE condition? What are you comparing it to?

Comment: @DavidMakogon resetPassword is an array so resetPassword.oneTimeCode won't work. If it will work if I do resetPassword[0].oneTimeCode but please review the question as I am trying to check if the same code is not repeated twice. I am trying to write a query and I am new to Cosmos to I am not sure.

Comment: I'm just saying, you have a syntax error. You can't just reference a property like that. Since you're searching through an array, you should look at `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`. You probably should edit your question to be clear about the desired output/results from your query as well.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Will Array_Contains search for duplicates in the whole document? I am trying to find duplicates not based on one value. For example: oneTimeCode is generated automatically and it generates value is 345, I want to check if the same value is generated again

Comment: No - it just returns true/false. I suggest reading the docs more to see about how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDb and any non-relational database is different from SQL when querying. You have to access first the topmost child/property (resetPassword) and since its value is an array of objects, you can use CosmosDb built-in ARRAY_CONTAINS array function.

```
select * from password-reset where array_contains(password-reset.resetPassword, {"hug3jh"}, true)
```

Take note of the 3rd boolean param- partial match checker.  If it evaluates to 'true' and if the specified search value is an object, the command checks for a partial match (the search object is a subset of one of the objects). If it evaluates to 'false', the command checks for a full match of all objects within the array.

Then you can apply your aggregate functions as needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-aggregate-functions